# What is the simplest but most effective way in formatting strings into a chart in Java?

Tags: java, string, formatting, output

For my program, I need to display the item description, quantity, and price in a chart-like format. So that means that description of item 1 would be in line with its price and quantity. So far, I've tried several methods I found on the Internet but haven't succeeded. I am using Dr. Java so please suggest something that is compatible with that compiler.
Thank you in advance!

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String []args){
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  String sentinel = "End";

   String description[] = new String[100];

   int quantity[] = new int[100];

   double price [] = new double[100];
   int i = 0;
   // do loop to get input from user until user enters sentinel to terminate data entry
   do
   {
     System.out.println("Enter the Product Description or " + sentinel + " to stop");
     description[i] = input.next();

     // If user input is not the sentinal then get the quantity and price and increase the index
     if (!(description[i].equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel))) {
       System.out.println("Enter the Quantity");
       quantity[i] = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter the Product Price ");
       price[i] = input.nextDouble();
     }
     i++;
   } while (!(description[i-1].equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel)));


  // companyArt();
   //System.out.print(invoiceDate());
   //System.out.println(randNum());



   System.out.println("Item Description: ");
   System.out.println("-------------------");
   for(int a = 0; a <description.length; a++){
     if(description[a]!=null){
      System.out.println(description[a]);
   }
 }  
   System.out.println("-------------------\n");


   System.out.println("Quantity:");
   System.out.println("-------------------");
   for(int b = 0; b <quantity.length; b++){
     if(quantity[b]!=0){
       System.out.println(quantity[b]);
     }
   } 
   System.out.println("-------------------\n");

   System.out.println("Price:");
   System.out.println("-------------------");
   for(int c = 0; c <price.length; c++){
     if(price[c]!=0){
       System.out.println("$"+price[c]);
     }
   } 
   System.out.println("-------------------");

   //This is where I multiply the price and quantity together to get the total
   double total = 0.0;
   for (int j = 0; j < quantity.length; j++){

     total += quantity[j] * price[j];
   }

   if(total != 0){
     System.out.println("Total: " + total);
   }       
  }
 }
```

Comment: Use a formatter :)

Comment: *"I am using Dr. Java so please suggest something that is compatible with that compiler."* - The compiler is irrelevant.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you want? We can try to guess, but why should we. You want our help, so please be specific to what you need. And which part you are having trouble with.

Comment: *"So far, I've tried several methods I found on the Internet but haven't succeeded."* - Please explain the problems you had.  This question is not far from being closed as "Too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code prints out a list of item descriptions, followed by a list of quantities, followed by a list of prices. I'm assuming this is not how you want it to look. The best solution would be to use a single `for` loop that prints each of these three things out per line. The following code prints out a table with three columns labelled "Item Description", "Quantity", and "Price", with each row representing an item, and dashed lines separating each row:

```
System.out.println("Item Description:\tQuantity:\tPrice:\t");
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
for(int a = 0; a <description.length; a++){
    if (description[a].equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(description[a] + "\t\t" + quantity[a] + "\t\t" + price[a]);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

The output will be formatted like this:

```
Item Description:   Quantity:   Price:  
---------------------------------------------------------
asdfaoiew;rjlkf     248         4309.0
---------------------------------------------------------

asodifaasd          43          2323.0
---------------------------------------------------------

asdfasoif           234         2.0
---------------------------------------------------------
```

If the columns don't line up properly, you'll need to either add or remove one "\t" after the description, depending on how long or short your item descriptions are.